# Find Common Values From Datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I Have about 10 (DatagridView Count may varies As per User Selected Files From 2 to 10) Datagridview  ,So How can i find common value from all Datagridviews ??

Comment If you need more brief details

Below is mine but It find common from 2 -2 datagridviews

```
 For i As Integer = 1 To dgvCont
        For j As Integer = 0 To Main.DGVM(i).Rows.Count - 1
            For Each Val As DataGridViewRow In Main.DGVM(i + 1).Rows
                If Val.Cells(0).Value = Main.DGVM(i).Rows.Item(j).Cells(0).Value Then
                    Dim cm As String = Val.Cells(0).Value
                    If cm = "" Then

                    Else
                        Analysis.lvCmn.Items.Add(Val.Cells(0).Value)
                    End If
                End If
            Next
        Next
    Next
```

Comment: @SenthilKumar Check it now

Comment: Are you using multiple datagridview

Comment: For i As integer = 0 to 10 DGVM(i) As Datagridview Next

Comment: @SenthilKumar yeah 10 datagridview

Comment: 10 datagridview have different values

Comment: @SenthilKumar 10 Datagridviews with common column structures but there may have common value from all and to find common from the each row like from all datagridviews 1'st row And one more thing that theres not fixed 10 datagrid view it may be from 2 to 10 ,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you want to set two nested loops accounting for an undetermined number of elements (items in an array of `DataGridView`, I presume), performing the checks you want:

```
 For count1 As Integer = 1 To dgvCont 'Assuming indices from 1 to dgvCont

     For row1 As Integer = 0 To Main.DGVM(count1).Rows.Count - 1
         If (Main.DGVM(count1).Rows(row1).Cells(0).Value Is Nothing) Then Continue For

         Dim val1 As String = Main.DGVM(count1).Rows(row1).Cells(0).Value
         Dim found As Boolean = False
         For count2 As Integer = 1 To dgvCont 'Assuming indices from 1 to dgvCont
             If (count2 = count1) Then Continue For

             For row2 As Integer = 0 To Main.DGVM(count2).Rows.Count - 1
                 If (Main.DGVM(count2).Rows(row2).Cells(0).Value Is Nothing) Then Continue For

                 Dim val2 As String = Main.DGVM(count2).Rows(row2).Cells(0).Value.ToString()
                 If val1 = val2 Then
                    Dim cm As String = val1
                    If cm = "" Then

                    Else
                        Analysis.lvCmn.Items.Add(val1)
                    End If

                    found = True
                    Exit For 'By assuming that you want to stop searching after finding a match
                 End If

             Next

             If (found) Then Exit For 'By assuming that you want to stop searching after finding a match
         Next
     Next
 Next
```

Your code is not too clear (neither what you want); but this should give you a good enough start to carry out the implementation you are looking for. Bear in mind that this code (like yours) only considers one column (first one); in case of wanting to iterate through all the columns, you would have to add further nested loops accounting for that.

Comment: I mean to found every possible common velue from all Datagridviews

Comment: @JadejaRJ this is what this code is doing with limitations (just looking in the first column and looking for just one match of each value). I hope that you understand that this is not a custom software development service and that this answer is way beyond what might be considered acceptable under the current conditions (question focused on your specific problems and not too much effort from your side (your code represents a pretty poor attempt)). Please, feel free to ask any question but I hope that my position is clear enough.

Comment: @JadejaRJ may I know why are not marking/unmarking the question? Is there anything unclear?

Comment: Sorry Sir But I have some doubts about your code , and dont know why but your code taking too much time to execute in just 3 datagridviews and 50 rows !!

Comment: @JadejaRJ Nothing to do with my code but with your requirements (looking for a lot) and with your original code (the one I edited). You might try different approaches (like LINQ-like one, for example), but I seriously doubt that there is anything quicker than loops for what you want, that is, testing everything against everything. The usual way to improve this kind of problems is defining the conditions better and avoiding a looking-for-everything-everywhere which is pretty time consuming...

Comment: @JadejaRJ other that (you defining the problem better, such that a lower number of iterations might be performed), there is no way to improve significantly the speed of the proposed loops (which, on top of that, quit after finding a match -> optimised as much as possible). On the other hand, this wasn't part of your original question: you asked for a way to allow your code to deal with an any number of  DataGridViews and this is what this answer is about. If you want something different (e.g., "I have this situation and I want to get this result; what is the most efficient way?"), you...

Comment: But it seems to be infinite loop

Comment: @JadejaRJ ... should post a new question. In any case, you are free to continue waiting here for someone willing to understand your exact requirements and to deliver what you want (if possible); but I consider that I have done already more than enough.

Comment: Ok Sir Thanks For your support but i would like to Go for better one perhaps i have to do some more effort . . . .

Comment: @JadejaRJ No, no... Let's put the ideas clear: this code is fine and delivers the best performance under these conditions (comparing DataGridViews, all the cells); there is no doubt there. If you don't know how to use it or the input conditions are different than what I assumed from your original code, this is a different story. There is nothing bad with this code. If you want to understand what you are doing wrong (because the code is doing everything fine), you can do a debugging by your own or post here your conditions and I might help you.